# Create a transformation so that a plane so that it is horizontal.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the plan $4x+5y+20z=20$, create a transformation so that it is horizontal (parallel to the $xy$-axis). Then, apply the same transformation to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=441$.

Honestly, I'm really confused by this question. My current attempt is taking the normal vector $\mathbf{n} = [4,5,20]$ and then trying to rotate that to the vector $\bigl[0, 0, |\mathbf{n}|\bigr]$, but this is not helping me with the second part of the problem.

Comment: Does the transformation have to be orthogonal as in your attempt?

Comment: @TravisWillse not sure what you mean by this question. The plane has to be parallel to the xy plane and orthogonal to the z-axis, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense. Can you proofread and edit?

Comment: The second part of the problem may not be correctly stated, since any rotation in space preserves that sphere.

Comment: An orthogonal transformation is one that preserves lengths (hence also angles). There are many transformations that are not orthogonal but which map a given plane to a horizontal one. In fact, the (singular) transformation $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y, 0)$ maps any nonvertical plane to the $xy$-plane. It's not clear from your question statement, whether that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work out the rotation that you describe (and it would have nice *extra* properties as an isometry, e.g. preserving angles and lengths), but that takes more effort than is necessary.

Instead, think about a linear transformation that sends
$\begin{bmatrix} x & y & z \end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}} 
\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} X & Y & Z \end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}}$,
where output vector lies on a horizontal plane, assuming that the input vector began on the given plane. In other words, we know that $4x + 5y + 20z = 20$ and we want $Z = c$ for some scalar $c$.

Let's write down a [shear transformation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Shear_mapping) $T$ that leaves the first two coordinates alone, i.e. $X = x$ and $Y = y$, and maps $Z = z + ax + by$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$. If we're clever, we can use the defining linear relation to get the what we want:
$$
20Z = 20(z + \tfrac15x + \tfrac14y) = 20z + 4x + 5y = 20
$$
or $Z = 1$, a horizontal plane. So, we require $a = \tfrac15$ and $b = \tfrac14$. All together, this looks like

> $$ \begin{cases} X = \phantom{\tfrac15}x \\ Y = \phantom{\tfrac15x + \tfrac14}y \\ Z = \tfrac15x + \tfrac14y + z \end{cases} $$

In terms of the standard basis, the transformation is represented by the matrix

> $$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \tfrac15 & \tfrac14 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, $$

and you can apply it to vectors on the original plane to check that they indeed all land on the plane $Z = 1$. For example, the calculation
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \tfrac15 & \tfrac14 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
shows that
$\begin{bmatrix} x & y & z \end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}} 
\mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} X & Y & Z \end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}} 
= \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{\mathsf{T}}$. In the former, $4x + 5y + 20z = 20$, and in the latter, $Z = 1$.

Perhaps you can apply this transformation to the sphere?

Comment: Why work so hard? Why not rotate and preserve the sphere? The original question seems ill-defined.

Comment: I mean, is it not *more* work to determine the rotation? I guess you could do it as a composition of two rotations about the $x$ and $y$ axes so it's not so bad.